# How to include NULL values in aggregate function COUNT() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The aggregate query groups by attribute A3 and then performs a COUNT(A4) but it doesn't consider the NULL values in the attribute A4.

[image: I want the COUNT function to include counts of NULL values in attribute A4]

Answer (score 2):

For a regular count, don't include the column name:

```
count(*)
```

For count distinct, just add the extra value back in:

```
count(distinct a4) + (case when count(a4) <> count(*) then 1 else 0 end)
```

This can be simplified in MySQL to:

```
count(distinct a4) + (count(a4) <> count(*))
```

Or, if you know there is value that won't exist in the column:

```
count(distinct coalesce(a4, ' <NULL>'))
```